# Install a deb inside a chroot

Tags: tar, apt-get, chroot

I have (or soon will have) a puppet script that installs a number of packages via apt-get. I need them to be accessible from inside a chroot. Is there an easy way to set that up?

My first thought is to run apt-get from inside the chroot but that seems both messy and to be a potential problem as how can I be sure I've completely removed apt-get when I'm done?

As a side note: once I get the jail set up, I should be able to tar it up and move it around right?

---

In case it matters, the things I need include `gcc-multilib` `g++-multilib` `libc6-i386` and `libc6-dev-i386`